# How can I take a random input value as a slot variable in Google Actions NLP (google assistant) Console?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nlp, actions-on-google, nlu

Let say I have an app where I want to give someone the weather in a city.

The first scene has a prompt: "What city would you like the weather of?"

I then have to collect a slot/parameter called conv.param.city: and then use it in my node webhook which is:

```
const { conversation } = require('@assistant/conversation');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const app = conversation();

app.handle('schedule', (conv, {location}) => {  
  let temperature = callApi(location);// this part doesn't matter right now

  **conv.add(`You want to know the weather in ${location}`);
  conv.close(`The weather in ${location} is ${temperature}`);
});

exports.ActionsOnGoogleFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

From what I can tell, you can only take in parameters/slots that are predefined by types/intents. I cannot make a list of all cities that exist to train with. How can I basically say: Whatever the user says at this point, make that word into this variable.

How can i do this with the Google Actions SDK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by setting your intent parameter type to be free text (here's an [example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-snowpal-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/types/word.yaml) from one of the sample repos).

```
freeText: {}
```

If you apply this type to an intent parameter, you can use the training phrases to provide the necessary context on where in the phrase that "word" should be matched ([example](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-builder-snowpal-nodejs/blob/master/sdk/custom/intents/guess.yaml) from the same repo).

> I cannot make a list of all cities that exist to train with.

Another option exists if your API can return the set of locations supported. You can also use [runtime type overrides](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/webhooks?tool=sdk#runtime_type_overrides) to dynamically generate the type from the list of list of locations the API provides. This will be more accurate, but is dependent on what your data source looks like.